# Insert link into database as a href tag

Tags: php

I am having an issue by inserting a link in the database. I am generating links through several conditions but in the end, I get an error when I try to insert a link in the database.

Also, I am pulling a description from the database then adding these links to the existing description and then updating the value.

```
$parent_path = 'https://sitename.com/game/'.$parentSlug;

$parentLink = '<a href="'.$parent_path.'">'.$parentName.'</a>';


$child_path = 'https://sitename.com/game/'.$slug;

$childLink = '<a href="'.$child_path.'">'.$name.'</a>';
```

I am facing several errors during a script run

Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 's also a CBD education section to help you make the best decision when making...'

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `wpdev_postmeta` where post_id = $post_id  and meta_key = 'test'";

$q = $conn->query($sql);
     
while($r = $q -> fetch()){ 
    $description = $r['meta_value']; 
}
```

$description may contain "a href  tag ", when I echo it, it becomes a clickable link and not able to update field in db.

```
$desc = $description.'<br/>'.$parentLink.$childLink;

$stmt = "UPDATE wpdev_postmeta SET  meta_value = '$desc' WHERE meta_key  = 'test' and post_id = $post_id ";
      
if ($conn->query($stmt)) {
      echo "Record updated successfully". '<br/>';
} else {
      echo "Error updating record: " . '<br/>';
}
```

For future reference, do I need to get data first from database then send it again with new update in case I don't want to lose what is inserted before? I was googling but couldnt find appropriate answer.

Comment: You're open to SQL injection. You should use prepared statment https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: this will be just a script which will update some records to db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If  you need save HTML to database you can use two different way

1. Using prepared statements. Look to [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) or [MySLi](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)
2. Encoding all tags and other special symbols for example via `htmlentities` or `htmlspecialchars`.

Example for `htmlentities`:

```php
<?php
    $link = '<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">Check that</a>';
    echo(htmlentities($link, ENT_QUOTES|ENT_HTML5));
    // output:
    /*
    &lt;a href&equals;&quot;https&colon;&sol;&sol;stackoverflow&period;com&sol;&quot;&gt;Check that&lt;&sol;a&gt;
    */
?>
```

For decode to HTML use `html_entity_decode`

```php
<?php
    $encoded = '&lt;a href&equals;&quot;https&colon;&sol;&sol;stackoverflow&period;com&sol;&quot;&gt;Check that&lt;&sol;a&gt;';
    echo(html_entity_decode($encoded, ENT_QUOTES|ENT_HTML5));
    // output
    /*
    <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">Check that</a>
    */
?>
```

Example for `htmlspecialchars`:

```php
<?php
    $link = '<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">Check that</a>';
    echo(htmlspecialchars($link, ENT_QUOTES|ENT_HTML5));
    // output
    /*
    &lt;a href=&quot;https://stackoverflow.com/&quot;&gt;Check that&lt;/a&gt;
    */
?>
```

For decode from `htmlspecialchars`:

```php
<?php
    $encoded = '&lt;a href=&quot;https://stackoverflow.com/&quot;&gt;Check that&lt;/a&gt;';
    echo(htmlspecialchars_decode($encoded, ENT_QUOTES|ENT_HTML5));
    // output
    /*
    <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">Check that</a>
    */
?>
```